# How can I create an object inside a class?

Tags: php, class

How can I do this, as the most obvious way doesn't work:

```
<?php

    class Inner {

    public $var;
    }

    class Outer {

    $test = new Inner;
    }

?>
```

Yields:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /f5/debate/public/test.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP you can't instantiate a class as a default value of a property. You need to do it in a function (in this case, probably likely the constructor). eg.

```
class Inner {
    public $var;
}

class Outer {
    public $test;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->test = new Inner();
    }
}
```